# Datatables: server-side processing with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, datatables

Is there anyone who's been able to get server-side processing working in dataTables 1.10 using MongoDB and PHP? I know there's a sample script using the deprecated API available at http://datatables.net/development/server-side/php_mongodb,but I'd like and example using a more recent version.

Thanks!
M